# Architecture for a web2py + ember + websockets application

Tags: ember.js, websocket, ember-data, web2py

I am trying to add a quasi-real-time layer to my `Ember` web application `via websockets`. I am thinking about the following setup:

```
frontend client <--> web2py server (REST API) <--->    ------
      ^                                                | DB |
      |---> websockets server <--> BG services <-->    ------
```

Whenever the frontend is logging in to my web2py server, which is providing the REST API to access the data needed by the frontend, it must also connect to a "websockets server". This server will be used by the BG services to provide quasi-real-time data to the connected frontends.

The BG services are background processes which are extracting complex data from the database, without a request coming from the frontend, and pushing this data to the connected clients, whenever it is ready.

I have some questions which I have answered for myself (I could be wrong here, please correct me):

- A1: How to know which are the connected clients? I guess the websockets server knows which clients are connected
- A2: How to push messages to the frontends? Just send a message to the websockets server, specifying the group to which it must be distributed.
- A3: How to organize "websocket groups"? Design a strategy according to your data: for example, if all the members of a group must receive the data belonging to a certain "organization", create a websockets group for each organization: then just push to that org-group, and all connected frontends belonging to that org-group will receive the data.
- A4: How to push JSON? [Encode it first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications), and send it as text. Decode on the client. (Websockets can send [text and binary data](http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html)).

I am not sure about the following:

- B1: How to push to different endpoints in the frontend? For example, how to push to `persons`, `posts`, `comments`?
- B2: How to use a single server for the REST API and the websockets server?

According to [EmberSockets](https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberSockets/blob/master/example/js/application.js):

```
$window.App = Ember.Application.create({

    Socket: EmberSockets.extend({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8888,
        controllers: ['index']
    })

});
```

And according to the documentation on the [RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_url-host):

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

Is it possible to have a single host URL to handle the ws and the http connection? I do not think having the frontend connecting to two different hosts (specially two different ports, which are maybe blocked in the customer network) is a good idea.

- B3: What server can I use for websockets? Currently I am using apache for http. I could use for example [Tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado), which supports websockets, but how do I make Tornado and apache play together? How do I tell the client to do http connections to apache, and ws connections to Tornado, by using a single URL? Is this just a matter of tweaking the apache config, and redirect the ws connections to another server?